# How to replace elements in a list using dictionary lookup

Tags: python, list, replace

Given this list

```
my_lst = ['LAC', 'HOU', '03/03 06:11 PM', '2.13', '1.80', '03/03 03:42 PM']
```

I want to change its `0th` and `1st` values according to the dictionary value:

```
def translate(my_lst):
    subs = {
        "Houston": "HOU", 
        "L.A. Clippers": "LAC",

    }
```

so the list becomes:

```
['L.A. Clippers', 'Houston', '03/03 06:11 PM', '2.13', '1.80', '03/03 03:42 PM']
```

Comment: Why isn't your dict flipped?

Comment: can key keys and values of `subs` be swapped `subs = {"HOU": "Houston", "LAC": "L.A. Clippers",}`

Comment: This is on purpose, I need a solution so replace acc. to dict values.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Seems like everybody likes reverse dictionaries

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If all values are unique then you should reverse the dict first to get an efficient solution:

```
>>> subs = {
...         "Houston": "HOU", 
...         "L.A. Clippers": "LAC",
... 
...     }
>>> rev_subs = { v:k for k,v in subs.iteritems()}
>>> [rev_subs.get(item,item)  for item in my_lst]
['L.A. Clippers', 'Houston', '03/03 06:11 PM', '2.13', '1.80', '03/03 03:42 PM']
```

If you're only trying to updated selected indexes, then try:

```
indexes = [0, 1]
for ind in indexes:
    val =  my_lst[ind]
    my_lst[ind] = rev_subs.get(val, val)
```

Comment: Actually I have another function that replaces elements according to dict key and I just wanted to use flag `reverse`, that's why I'm looking for solution I described in the OP to do the job.

Comment: Then you can construct the reversed dictionary (and then use it naturally): `reverse_subs = {v: k for k, v in subs.items()}`

Answer (score 11):

If the values are unique, then you can flip the dictionary:

```
subs = {v:k for k, v in subs.iteritems()}
```

Then you can use `.get()` to get the value from a dictionary, along with a second parameter incase the key is not in the dictionary:

```
print map(subs.get, my_lst, my_lst)
```

Prints:

```
['L.A. Clippers', 'Houston', '03/03 06:11 PM', '2.13', '1.80', '03/03 03:42 PM']
```

Comment: This got me close to an answer, but on Python 3 at least printing `map(subs.get, my_lst, my_lst)` returns a map object (e.g. `<map object at 0x000002DE7F3EFB50>`). `list(map(subs.get, my_lst, my_lst))` works though.

Answer (score 8):

if you want something shorter, you can exploit the `series` function in `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
A = ['A','B','A','C','D'] #list we want to replace with a dictionary lookup
B = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3,'D':4} #dictionary lookup, dict values in B will be mapped to entries in A
C = (pd.Series(A)).map(B) #convert the list to a pandas series temporarily before mapping
D = list(C) # we transform the mapped values (a series object) back to a list
# entries in D = [1,2,1,3,4]
```

Comment: This is elegant but requires that each list item is represented in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the dict, then just apply the lookup to the first 2 elements of your list:

```
subs = {
    "Houston": "HOU", 
    "L.A. Clippers": "LAC",

}

my_lst = ['LAC', 'HOU', '03/03 06:11 PM', '2.13', '1.80', '03/03 03:42 PM']
my_lst[:2] = map(dict(zip(subs.values(), subs)).get, my_lst[:2])
print my_lst
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-line in pandas ....

```
df['A'].replace(dict(zip(
        ['SERVICIOS', 'ECON?MICO', 'ECONOMICO', 'EN ESPECIE'],
        ['servicios', 'economico', 'economico', 'en especie'])
                       ),regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ashwini-chaudhary
https://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/ashwini-chaudhary
Update for Python3, use items() instead of iteritems()

```
rev_subs = { v:k for k,v in subs.items()}
```