# Python: Replace matches in list of strings according to replacement dict / replacement map

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

What's the best way to archieve this:

```
original_list = ["word_1", "word_2", "word"]
replacements = {
  'word_1': 'something',
  'word': 'number'
}
updated_list = replace_in_list(original_list, replacements)
```

where

```
updated_list == ["something", "word_2", "number"]
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295776/how-to-replace-elements-in-a-list-using-dictionary-lookup - Also similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882448/replacing-a-word-in-a-list-with-a-value-from-a-dict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a list comprehension where you access replacement dict key, with default value as original string if not found (using `get`):

```
updated_list = [replacements.get(x,x) for x in original_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```
>>> [replacements[w] if w in replacements else w for word in original_list]
['something', 'word_2', 'number']
```

Comment: That's what I would have made

Comment: It's quite pythonic to use a conditional expression in a list comprehension!