# Replacing list values with dictionary values

Tags: python

I have a sample code that does not seem to work well, I have tried different solution online but have failed.

I have a list known as `lv` which scraps a website and returns special divs which are dynamic (change everytime when the code is run).

```
lv = ['div5', 'div3', 'div4', 'div1', 'div2']
```

i have a list know as `nv` which contains the type of text to be replaced,

```
nv = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4', 'div5']
```

I also have a dictionary named as `mm` which sets `nv` values to some values

```
mm = {nv[0]:'type1',nv[1]:'type2',nv[2]:'type3', nv[3]:'type4',  nv[4]:'type5'}
```

Now I would like to print the results using inde method as `lv[0:5]` and for every value in this it should check if the value corresponds to `nv` value then replace that value with dictionary value

```
print(lv[0:5])
#output should be like this
'type1','type3','type4','type2', 'type1'
```

Here is my full original source code:

'''python

```
    lv = [l for l in cur.find_all(id=levels)]

    nv = [
        '<div id="map-innercontainer-weak3" style="background-image:none"> </div>',
        '<div id="map-innercontainer-strong3"> </div>',
        '<div id="map-innercontainer-strong2"> </div>',
        '<div id="map-innercontainer-strong1"> </div>',
        '<div id="map-innercontainer-weak1"> </div>',
        '<div id="map-innercontainer-weak2"> </div>',
        '<div id="map-innercontainer-weak3"> </div>',
    ]

    mm = {
        nv[0]:'',
        nv[1]:'Strong3',
        nv[2]:'Strong2',
        nv[3]:'Strong1',
        nv[4]:'Weak1',
        nv[5]:'Weak2',
        nv[6]:'Weak3',
    }


    # #Show out the results to the user
    print(f'Currency\t\tStrength\n')
    print(f'{pairs[0].text}\t\t\t{lv[0:6]}\n')
    print(f'{pairs[1].text}\t\t\t{lv[6:12]}\n')
    print(f'{pairs[2].text}\t\t\t{lv[12:18]}\n')
    print(f'{pairs[3].text}\t\t\t{lv[18:24]}\n')
    print(f'{pairs[4].text}\t\t\t{lv[24:30]}\n')
    print(f'{pairs[5].text}\t\t\t{lv[30:36]}\n')
```

**IT OUTPUTS THIS BUT I WOULD LIKE TO REPLACE THE DIVS WITH DICT VALUES**

```
    Currency        Strength

    EURO            [<div id="map-innercontainer-weak3" style="background-image:none"> </div>, <div id="map-innercontainer-weak3" style="background-image:none"> </div>, <div id="map-innercontainer-weak3" style="background-image:none"> </div>, <div id="map-innercontainer-weak3" style="background-image:none"> </div>, <div id="map-innercontainer-weak3" style="background-image:none"> </div>, <div id="map-innercontainer-weak3"> </div>]
```

Comment: What have you actually tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace elements in a list using dictionary lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295776/how-to-replace-elements-in-a-list-using-dictionary-lookup)

Comment: I am trying to scrap a website, its divs are constant its only that they change with time like div1 can be first then it can be third that why

Comment: I understood your problem, it is expected to show the efforts you made to actually solve your own problem. BTW, your expected output does not match what you describe

Comment: I have Edited my question to show my efforts

Comment: It is not necessary to put **ALL** your code. A [mre] would be enough

Comment: okay what can i do from that point, i have edited

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for list comprehension, e.g. using the below code:

```
print([ mm[item] for item in lv ])
```

What this does is to loop through all the elements of lv in order (as you describe), and prints a list where every element of the list is the value that the corresponding element in lv is the key for.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple for loop to try and solve this. It loops through the length of the lv list and sets each lv item to the corresponding item in the dictionary.

```
for i in range(len(lv)):
    lv[i] = mm[lv[i]]
```

Output:
['type5', 'type3', 'type4', 'type1', 'type2']

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, i used this two functions to remove multiple strings

```py
def multiple_replacer(*key_values):
    replace_dict = dict(key_values)
    replacement_function = lambda match: replace_dict[match.group(0)]
    pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k, v in key_values]), re.M)
    return lambda string: pattern.sub(replacement_function, string)

def multiple_replace(string, *key_values):
    return multiple_replacer(*key_values)(string)
```

now the output gives me what i want.

```
EURO            [ weak3  ,  weak3  ,  weak3  ,  weak3  ,  weak2 ,  weak3 ]
```